# delete all subdomain and Get Root Domain only pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a big list is a json file an example :

```
{"timestamp":"1600840155","name":"0.0.0.1","value":"subdomain.test.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600840155","name":"0.0.0.2","value":"test.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600846210","name":"0.0.0.3","value":"node-fwx.pool-1-0.dynamic.exmple4.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600846210","name":"0.0.0.4","value":"exmple4.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600848078","name":"0.0.0.5","value":"node-fwy.pool-1-0.dynamic.exmple5.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600848078","name":"0.0.0.6","value":"exmple5.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600838189","name":"0.0.0.7","value":"node-fwz.pool-1-0.dynamic.exmple6.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600838189","name":"0.0.0.8","value":"exmple6.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600879127","name":"0.0.0.9","value":"node-fx0.pool-1-0.dynamic.exmple7.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600838189","name":"0.0.0.10","value":"exmple7.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600874834","name":"0.0.0.11","value":"node-fx1.pool-1-0.dynamic.exmple8.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600838189","name":"0.0.0.12","value":"exmple8.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600825122","name":"0.0.0.13","value":"node-ftb.pool-1-0.dynamic.exmple9.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600838189","name":"0.0.0.14","value":"exmple9.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600849239","name":"0.0.0.15","value":"node-fx2.pool-1-0.dynamic.exmple10.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600838189","name":"0.0.0.16","value":"exmple10.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600820784","name":"0.0.0.17","value":"node-fx3.pool-1-0.dynamic.other11.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600838189","name":"0.0.0.18","value":"exmple11.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600840955","name":"0.0.0.19","value":"node-fx4.pool-1-0.dynamic.other12.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600838189","name":"0.0.0.20","value":"exmple12.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600860091","name":"0.0.0.21","value":"another -one.pool-1-0.dynamic.other13.net","type":"hd"}
{"timestamp":"1600838189","name":"0.0.0.22","value":"exmple13.net","type":"hd"}
```

and I would like to get just the the root only and delete the other one using pyspark
so  want to select

```
df.select("name","value","type").distinct() \
.write \
.save("mycleanlist",format="json")
```

i want this result

```
"name":"0.0.0.22","value":"exmple13.net","type":"hd"}
"name":"0.0.0.2","value":"test.net","type":"hd"}
"name":"0.0.0.4","value":"exmple4.net","type":"hd"}
"name":"0.0.0.6","value":"exmple5.net","type":"hd"}
"name":"0.0.0.8","value":"exmple6.net","type":"hd"}
"name":"0.0.0.10","value":"exmple7.net","type":"hd"}
"name":"0.0.0.12","value":"exmple8.net","type":"hd"}
"name":"0.0.0.14","value":"exmple9.net","type":"hd"}
"name":"0.0.0.16","value":"exmple10.net","type":"hd"}
"name":"0.0.0.18","value":"exmple11.net","type":"hd"}
"name":"0.0.0.20","value":"exmple12.net","type":"hd"}
"name":"0.0.0.22","value":"exmple13.net","type":"hd"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [UDF](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html) to wrap a method that extract the root domain:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def extract_domain(url):
  if url:
    parts = url.split('.')
    url = '.'.join(parts[-2:])
  return url
extract_domain_udf = udf(extract_domain, StringType())

df.select("name", extract_domain_udf("value"), "type").distinct() \
.write \
.save("mycleanlist",format="json")
```

Comment: spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 605, in main
    process()

Comment: Do you have the full exception trace? The column 'value' is always populated?

Comment: du -sh mycleanlist/
3.3G mycleanlist/
root@vmi318702:/home/Downloads# du -sh mycleanlist/
4.2G mycleanlist/
root@vmi318702:/home/Downloads# du -sh mycleanlist/
4.0K mycleanlist/
and the error  shows up

Comment: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'". Will need to verify the url is not None before split

Comment: import os
import csv
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, countDistinct
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

df = spark.read.json("list.json")

def extract_domain(url):
  parts = url.split('.')
  return '.'.join(parts[-2:])
extract_domain_udf = udf(extract_domain, StringType())

df.select("name", extract_domain_udf("value")).write \
.save("mycleanlist",format="csv")

Comment: I updated the answer adding a if that checks the url before do the split.